# Lightning Collapsible and Accordion Dynamic aura id for sections

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have designed an Account and its Contacts relationship in lightning Collapsible and Accordion style. The data populating correctly but since it is under aura:iteration, everytime it is getting the same Id for expand and collapse.

This is Account names without expanding 
[image]

Now, **when I click on single account to see the contacts, it is expanding all the accounts**.
[image]

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="collapseSecController">
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <div class="slds-p-around--large">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
            <div class="slds-page-header" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="{!c.sectionOne}">
                <section class="slds-clearfix">
                    <div class="slds-float--left ">
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:add" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates add"/>
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:dash" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates dash"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-m-left--large">{!acc.Name}</div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="articleOne">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
                       role="grid">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Header Code
                            </th>
                           <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Account Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Manufacturer
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Asset Code
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Serial Number
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!acc.Contacts}" var="con">

                           <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                                    {!acc.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="accName">
                                    {!con.AccountName__c}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="prName">
                                    {!con.ProductName__c}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!acc.Manufacturer__c}
                                </td>   
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!con.HdrName__c}
                                </td> 
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!con.Mfrserialnumber__c}
                                </td> 

                            </tr>

                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>      

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAccountAndContactsRelation(component);
    },

    sectionOne : function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.helperFun(component,event,'articleOne');
    }
})
```

Helper.js

```
 ({
        getAccountAndContactsRelation : function(cmp) {
            var action = cmp.get("c.getAccountAndContactsRelation");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    cmp.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());


         }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    helperFun : function(component,event,secId) {
      var acc = component.find(secId);
            for(var cmp in acc) {
            $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-show');  
            $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-hide');  
       }
    },
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using lightning:accordion and lightning:accordionSection components which is very simpler for handling.

Reference: [lightning:accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_accordion.htm)

Check this out:

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountsController">
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<lightning:accordion activeSectionName="B">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc" indexVar="ind">
        <lightning:accordionSection name="{!ind}" label="{!acc.Name}">
            {!acc.Name} - {!acc.Phone}
             //Add your table & data here
        </lightning:accordionSection>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:accordion>
```

Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getAccountAndContactsRelation(component);
}
```

Helper:

```
 getAccountAndContactsRelation : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.getAcc");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('response.getReturnValue()',response.getReturnValue());
            cmp.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());


        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Class:

```
public class AccountsController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAcc(){
        return [SELECT id,name,Phone FROM Account LIMIT 4];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will give the same ui of what I posted?

Comment: Yes, This will give you a neat and organised ui.
And more responsive to all devices.
You may refer lightning design System -https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/
And you can handle actions more easily.
Has a collection of attributes that can be passed for user's need.
Can also be customised.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen you should use this in build component.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tweak the code so that only for the current target element the toggle is active while for rest it is inactive .

```
helperFun : function(component,event,secId) {
  var acc = component.find(secId);
  acc.forEach(function(element) {
        $A.util.toggleClass(element, "slds-hide");
    });
    $A.util.addClass(event.target, "slds-show");
}
```

Alternatively create a separate child component to represent your section and then component.find will have only instance and rest of them are segregated .

Create a component called collapisbleSection like below

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account"/>
   <div class="slds-page-header" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="{!c.sectionOne}">
            <section class="slds-clearfix">
                <div class="slds-float--left ">
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:add" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates add"/>
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:dash" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates dash"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-m-left--large">{!v.acc.Name}</div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="articleOne">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
                   role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Header Code
                        </th>
                       <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Account Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Product Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Manufacturer
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Asset Code
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Serial Number
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.acc.Contacts}" var="con">

                       <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                                {!v.acc.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="accName">
                                {!con.AccountName__c}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="prName">
                                {!con.ProductName__c}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!v.acc.Manufacturer__c}
                            </td>   
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!con.HdrName__c}
                            </td> 
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!con.Mfrserialnumber__c}
                            </td> 

                        </tr>

                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     <aura:component >
```

The controller will be as below

```
({
  sectionOne : function(component, event, helper) {
     var acc = component.find('articleOne');
     $A.util.toggleClass(acc, 'slds-show');  
  }
})
```

Now the parent component will be modified as below

```
<aura:component controller="collapseSecController">
  <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div class="slds-p-around--large">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
        <c:collapisbleSection acc="{!acc}"/>
      </aura:iteration>
     </div>
  </aura:component>
```

Also if your styling needs are one matching the lightning design system , use the latest [lightning:accordian](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_accordion.htm) tag

Comment: I have tried the same helperFun but no luck.

Comment: Getting error for the above alternative method 
`Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key 'acc.Contacts'. No value provider was found for 'acc'. : false
Callback failed: apex://collapseSecController/ACTION$getAccountAndContactsRelation`

Comment: Looks like I missed to use v dot .check the updated code .

Comment: Can we also add collapse all and expand all with this example. I tried but, couldn't get rid of it. @MohithShrivastava

Answer (score 0):

`allowMultipleSectionsOpen="false"` or `true`, set this in accordionsection and it will work

Answer (score -1):

Above solution works with minor changes. Please refer below.

//Parent Component

```
<aura:component controller="collapseSecController">
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div class="slds-p-around--large">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
        <c:collapisbleSection acc="{!acc}"/>
      </aura:iteration>
     </div>
    </aura:component>
```

//Parent cmp controller

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getAcc");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('response.getReturnValue()',response.getReturnValue());
                cmp.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

//Collapsible Child Component

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account"/>
   <div class="slds-page-header" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="{!c.sectionOne}">
            <section class="slds-clearfix">
                <div class="slds-float--left ">
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:add" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates add"/>
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:dash" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates dash"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-m-left--large">{!v.acc.Name}</div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="articleOne">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
                   role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Header Code
                        </th>
                       <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Account Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Product Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Manufacturer
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Asset Code
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                            Serial Number
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.acc.Contacts}" var="con">

                       <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                                {!v.acc.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="accName">
                                {!con.AccountName__c}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="prName">
                                {!con.ProductName__c}
                            </td>
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!v.acc.Manufacturer__c}
                            </td>   
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!con.HdrName__c}
                            </td> 
                            <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                {!con.Mfrserialnumber__c}
                            </td> 

                        </tr>

                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     <aura:component >
```

//Collapsible child Controller

```
({
    sectionOne : function(component, event, helper) {
        var acc = component.find('articleOne');
        acc.forEach(function(element) {
            $A.util.toggleClass(element, "slds-hide");
        });
        $A.util.addClass(event.target, "slds-show");
    },
    
    
})
```

Comment: This answer is a _code dump_. It doesn't explain what the differences are, or why those differences matter. The explanation is as important as the rest of the answer.

Comment: Please check the child javascript controller and you will get the difference. Anyone can easily go through the above code and figure out the differences. There is no need of further explanation. If you have any concerns, try the code in any console and see the result.

Comment: The onus is on _you_ to explain what the difference is.

Comment: Sorry Derek, that can’t be my responsibility. Can’t spoon feed everything